# Java invoke static method with Foreign Context / Check method for recursion

Tags: java, recursion, reflection, jvm

I wanted to check if a method uses recursion. So I wrote this mock up:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException {
        Method method = Child.class.getMethod("toBeTested", int.class);
        Object result = method.invoke(Super.class, 5);
        System.out.println((Integer) result);
    }
}


public class Super extends Child{

    public static int toBeTested(int a){
        System.out.println("validating recursion");
        return Child.toBeTested(a);
    }
}


public class Child {

    public static int toBeTested(int a){
        if(a==0)return 0;
        return toBeTested(a-1)+1;
    }
}
```

So I tried executing the method in Child with the Context of Super.class hoping in the recursion it would call the Super::toBeTested and I could hence validate the method uses recursion.

Is this even possible the way I tried? If no why not? Any other ideas to check foreign code for recursion...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't do that because that's not how static methods work, they don't have a "context" that decides what they call at runtime, it's decided at compile time (unless you want to call the classloader the context).

If it was a non-static method then you could do this:

```
public static class Child extends Super {

    public int toBeTested(int a){
        System.out.println("validating recursion");
        return super.toBeTested(a);
    }
}


public static class Super {

    public int toBeTested(int a){
        if(a==0)return 0;
        return toBeTested(a-1)+1;
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    Method method = Super.class.getMethod("toBeTested", int.class);
    Object result = method.invoke(new Child(), 5);
    System.out.println((Integer) result);
}
```

and it would print `validating recursion` 6 times because the method to be called depends on the runtime type of the object.

To check if static methods call themselves you could read the bytecode of the method (if you have access to it).